# Redirecting from subdomain without changing URL

Tags: apache, .htaccess, web

I want to redirect a subdomain with the .htaccess file without changing the URL. But can't figure it out.

ex. i want to turn

```
http://foo.domain.com
```

into

```
http://www.domain.com/users/foo/dashboard.php
```

I generated a script to do this, but the URL doesn't stay on http://foo.domain.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain.com/users/%1/dashboard.php [L]
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: `%1 => $1` $1 stands for the first group. In your case (.*)

Answer (score 0):

What you're htaccess it is doing is simply saying "if you find this, do a full redirect to that url"

Do this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^ dashboard.php?domain=%1 [L, QSA]
```

And it should work (moving to wherever dashboard is in your directory structure on-server, relatively)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (assuming that all the subdomains point to the root directory) :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ users/%1/dashboard.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Proxy flag [P] will do the trick:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options +Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.example\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule http://example.org/users/%1/dashboard.php [P,NC,QSA]
</IfModule>
```